# Setting all values of a 2d array (java)

Tags: java, arrays, printing, 2d, println

I am trying to fill a 7x6 blank 2d Array in java with a value of -1.

I initialized the array in a non-main class by typing:

```
int[][] anArray = new int[7][6];
```

Then I created a method setArray() which looks like the following:

```
public int[][] setArray()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {             
        for (int j = 0; j < 6 ; j++)
        {
            anArray[i][j] = -1;
        }
    }
return anArray;
}
```

but when I run this method through the main class, it returns the board as:

```
[[I@71988d36
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I'm fairly sure the above code is correct.

edit: Forgot a pair of curly braces.

Comment: Use `Arrays.deepToString(anArray);` if you want to see the content of your array.

Comment: Sorry for such a beginner question, but where would I want to put that piece of code? in my method, or somewhere in the main class where I run it?

Comment: Where you want to print the content of your array. You certainly did `System.out.println(anArray);` somewhere in your code. `deepToString` returns a String representation of the content of your array. So do `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(anArray));`

Answer (score 0):

Every class extending Object in Java (that is, all of them) inherits this method:

```
public String toString()
```

Which is called when you invoke to decide what to actually print

```
System.out.println()
```

The problem is, unless you override it, it will return something not very helpful which will get printed (except in a few cases such as String, int ....).

In this particular case, rather than overriding it, and as the comments above explain, it's easier to call a wrapper function that takes the array as a parameter and delivers a nice String as a result.